# How to access the element inside a struct contained in a struct in SPARC assmebly?

Tags: assembly, sparc

```
struct big{
    struct small;
}
struct small{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

If I pass in the pointer to big, and try to use

```
ld [%i0], %l0
```

to access the struct big, then how to access the variable a?
Can I use

```
ld [%l0 + OFFSET], %l0
```

to get it? It seems that this leads to a segfault.

Comment: You can't access either struct in assembly, you can only access the bytes, halfwords, and words that make up the struct. So you need to figure out how small is made up of these, and then how big is made up of them.

Comment: I don't know what assembler you use. struct small (inside of big) is not a pointer. If you dereference l0, you're landing on *a, I think this is not what you want. do not dereference small like a pointer

Comment: Is the `big` really just forward defining existence of `struct small`, or did you forget to put there member variable name, like `struct big{ struct small s; }`? So `big b; b.s.a = 1;` should be possible? If that is the case, then the `big` and `small` structures are effectively the same thing, doesn't matter if your code receives pointer to `big` or to `small`, it can manipulate the `a` and `b` in the same way. (unless you add virtual function to `big`, then the `.s.a` and `.s.b` *MAY* have different offset than the `.a` and `.b` inside the `small` struct, if `small` does NOT have virtual).

Comment: I mean, these things are compiler/implementation specific, the C structures are not binary portable by default. There are some techniques how to define C structure in binary reproducible way (setting padding to zero, using only POD types, no virtual functions, resolving endianness either by using only bytes/strings or by defining byte order for larger types, etc..), used for example when some SW is expected to open files stored at different platform. But if you just write normal C structure with few more variables and types, it will compile differently on different platforms/compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in a pointer to struct big, the very first thing it points to will be big.small.a, so after your first ld instruction, you've already got the value of big.small.a in %l0. If you try to dereference it again as a pointer, it's not surprising that you get a segfault. So basically what I'm saying is this:

```
ld [%i0], %l0    /* gives big.small.a */
ld [%i0+4], %l0  /* gives big.small.b */
```